# JavaScript. Assigning incorrect value in setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, asynchronous

I have a function that writes some text in the console after 3 seconds in the for a loop. Here it is:

```
const arr = [0, 0, 0, 0];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Index: " + i + ", element: " + arr[i]);
  }, 3000);
}
```

The problem is that the output in the console is not correct. It is as follows:

```
Index: 4, element: undefined
Index: 4, element: undefined
Index: 4, element: undefined
Index: 4, element: undefined
```

But I expect it to be like this:

```
Index: 0, element: undefined
Index: 1, element: undefined
Index: 2, element: undefined
Index: 3, element: undefined
```

Please, tell me what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: It's because, whenthe timeout has come, the for loop is finished and `i = 4`

Comment: you can give `i` as a parameter instead of closing over it, `var i = 4; setTimeout(function(a){ console.log(a) },3000,i); i = 0; console.log(i)`, the `a` will be 4, even i is set to 0 immediatly

Answer (score 2):

`for` loop doesn't waiting this time, it compiles the result and then presents the last one.

Get `setTimeout` function outside of `for` loop. :

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  const arr = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log("Index: " + i + ", element: " + arr[i]); 
  } 
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `let` instead of `var` to scope the inner-loop.

#### All at once...

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Index: " + i + ", element: " + arr[i]);
  }, 1000);
}
```

#### One-by-one...

If you want to print each one in a fixed-interval, multiply the timeout by the current index.

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Index: " + i + ", element: " + arr[i]);
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

Comment: This is actually a great example to show the difference between `let` and `var`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of skinning the same cat - using `forEach`

```
const arr=[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
arr.forEach( ( value, index )=>{
    setTimeout( ()=>{
        console.info('Index: %d, element: %s', index, value );
    },1000 );
});
```